# Windows - Where can I find a system() list of parameters?

Tags: operating-system, system

This is my first question here in StackOverflow, so if this question has already been made or is in the wrong topic, please excuse me.

I'm studying C using Windows and I'm looking for a list/book/manual of usable parameters for the system() function. Stuff like system("pause"), system("cls"), system("color 1f"), etc...

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The strings you pass to `system` have nothing to do with C. It's up to the OS. All the commands you used in your example are specific to Windows, I believe.

Comment: You just asked for the manual on all console commands ever... if you're on a Unix-based OS, you could start by listing the contents of `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and possibly other locations specified in the `$PATH` environment variable (which you can print with `echo "$PATH"` in a shell). From there, try running `man <some command>`, e.g. `man bash`, `man ls` or `man man` in the console.

Comment: Values available to `system()` are not a C question so much as an operating system one.  Post OS of interest and tag the post with that OS.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the mistakes. Already changed the tags. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of system() API is to execute an external command, the parameters are the arguments of the command that you are trying to execute, just like if you were typed in shell prompt, there is not anything special to pass, just put into the string.